# Java Webstart error when launching

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, java-web-start

I have an EJB 3.0 project using webstart that I am trying to deploy to JBoss AS 7.1.1 as a WAR. I can get to the html page just fine, but when I click the webstart link it tries to download JRE 1.7 from http://java.sun.com and pops up with this error:

```
"AutoDL?BundleId=68742" on java.sun.com is not a Java installer.
```

Here is the directory structure of my war:

```
root of war(dir)
-->GrahamsProjClient-webstart.jnlp
-->GrahamsProjStartAppPage.html
-->app(dir)
    -->GrahamsProjClient.jar(The actual client project)
-->META-INF(dir)
    -->context.xml(blank file)
    -->MANIFEST.MF
-->WEB-INF(dir)
    -->web.xml
    -->classes(dir) contains my compiled servlet
    -->lib(dir)
        -->jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
        -->jnlp-servlet.jar
```

Here are links to the important files from the war:

GrahamsProjClient-webstart.jnlp --> http://pastebin.com/zwkm1zz3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="$$codebase">
 <information>
     <title>Grahams Project</title>
     <vendor>Graham</vendor>
     <description>desc</description>
 </information>
 <resources>
   <j2se version="1.6"/>
   <jar href="GrahamsProjClient.jar"/>
 </resources>
 <application-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

GrahamsProjStartAppPage.html --> http://pastebin.com/EXu8Z5dZ

web.xml --> http://pastebin.com/KK3fPPY9

GrahamsProjServlet.java --> http://pastebin.com/iC9JDiTL

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with it for a while I ran into the solution. In the `GrahamsProjStartAppPage.html` the `deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton()` command needs to have `1.6.0+` instead of `1.6.0`. So the html file now looks like this:

```
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script src=
  "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP
    // file relative to HTML page
    var dir = location.href.substring(0,
        location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    //var url = dir + "GrahamsProjClient-webstart.jnlp";
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/GrahamsProjClient/GrahamsProjClient-webstart.jnlp"
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0+'); //changed from 1.6.0 to 1.6.0+
</script>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```